# Lab: calculate discounts

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm doing an exercise and so far so good as the code (after some help from other threads) now works **almost** fine, but...can't get the right results as a math point of view.

Here it's the code:

```
#getting base prices from user
item1 = float(input('Enter the price of the first item: '))
item2 = float(input('Enter the price of the second item: '))
clubc = raw_input('Does customer have a club card? (Y/N): ')
tax = float(input('Enter tax rate, e.g. 5.5 for 5.5% tax: '))
basep = (item1 + item2)
print('Base price = ', basep)

#setting variables for calculation
addtax = (1 + (tax / 100))

#conditions for output
if item1 >= item2 and clubc == 'N':
    priceafterd = float(item1 + (item2 / 2))
    print('Price after discounts = ', priceafterd)
    totalprice = (priceafterd * addtax)
    print('Total price = ', totalprice)
elif item2 >= item1 and clubc == 'N':
    priceafterd = float(item2 + (item1 / 2))
    print('Price after discounts = ', priceafterd)
    totalprice = (priceafterd * addtax)
    print('Total price = ', totalprice)

if item1 >= item2 and clubc == 'Y':
    priceafterd = float((item1 + (item2 / 2)) * 0.9)
    print('Price after discounts = ', priceafterd)
    totalprice = (priceafterd * var3)
    print('Total price = ' + totalprice)
else:
    priceafterd = float((item2 + (item1 / 2)) * 0.9)
    print('Price after discounts = ', priceafterd)
    totalprice = (priceafterd * var3)
    print('Total price = ' + totalprice)
```

The exercise requires to write a program that computes how much a customer has to pay after purchasing two items, depending on a promo, club card and taxes.

The problem is with the results. As an example of inputs:

```
Enter price of the first item: 10
Enter price of the second item: 20
Does customer have a club card? (Y/N): y
Enter tax rate, e.g. 5.5 for 5.5% tax: 8.25
Base price = 30.00
Price after discounts = 22.50
Total price = 24.36
```

Instead, I got:

```
line 33, in <module>
print('Total price = ' + totalprice)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

What's wrong with the syntax? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using python 2.x? If not, why are you using `raw_input`? And if so, why in 2021? :)

Comment: Ah you're right, bad habits are hard to remove! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

In the second conditional you wrote `print('Total price = ' + totalprice)` line instead of the `print('Total price = ', totalprice)`, and the problem is in that:

`totalprice` has `float` type, meanwhile `'Total price = '` is the `str` and what you are trying to do is almost like `str() + float()`, and because python doesn't know how to concatenate string and float number it raises an exception.

## How to solve

### 1) Use the same `print('Total price = ', totalprice)` line everywhere

> Why does it work and `print('Total price = ' + totalprice)` does not?

Because `print` automatically converts everything to string representation, you can imagine `print('Total price = ', totalprice)` expression like that:

`print(str('Total price = ') + " " + str(totalprice))`

### 2) Convert `float` to `str` and concatenate `str`s

`print('Total price = ' + str(totalprice))`

`str(totalprice)` converts `totalprice` from `float` to the `str` and python knows how to concatenate strings together.

### 3) Formatting

`"Total price = {}".format(3.14)"` is equivalent to the `"Total price = 3.14"` string,
so `print("Total price = {}".format(totalprice))` also will work

in python 3 we also have f-stings:

`f"Total price = {3.14}" == "Total price = 3.14"`

`print(f"Total price = {totalprice}")`